# Retrofit 2.0 : onResponse called with null when HTTP Code is 404

Tags: android, http-status-code-404, retrofit, okhttp

When REST Api returns 404, onResponse called with NULL Response. We have user search api and if the user is not found on the server our REST api returns 404 with error response in body with more details.

As Retrofit 2.0 returns a null response body, it's hard for us to show the correct error to the user.

Do we have an alternate solution to get a response during 404?

Response:
{"responseStatus":{"code":"00297","severity":"ERROR","message":"Profile not found..","info":"","status":404}}

HTTP Status Code:
404

Thanks

Comment: can you add your json result

Comment: @Tan Tran added response to the question

Comment: try to debug and find where the json comes from, maybe in onFailure method and parse it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrofit 2.0 shouldn't be returning a null response. If you are making an async callback and want the handle the error it should look something like this

```
     // Create a very simple REST adapter which points the GitHub API.
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(API_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();

// Create an instance of our GitHub API interface.
GitHub github = retrofit.create(GitHub.class);

// Create a call instance for looking up Retrofit contributors.
Call<List<Contributor>> call = github.contributors("square", "retrofit");

call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Item>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Item>> call, Response<ArrayList<Item>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                // do something
            }
            else {
                Log.e("Error Code", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                Log.e("Error Body", response.errorBody().toString());

                //display the appropriate message...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Item>> call, Throwable t) {

        }

});
```

Some of that code was copied from [Retrofit Samples](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/SimpleService.java). If you are getting a null response on a 404 something else is going wrong.

Comment: how can i  read my server's response in case of Error like severity , message ??